# Fluent nhibernate Automapping Domain Difficulties

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

Trying to get my head round automapping. I am having a problem when trying to automap my domain and generate the database. Im sure its something simple im doing wrong.

The problem is, the correct tables are generated, but only the ID field from the base class is present within the generated tables, none of the other fields within the entities are generated.

BaseEntity is in a different namespace to the entities.

Im not sure where to go from here, any ideas?

Here is my mapping configuration:

```
public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
  return _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(ConfigureDatabase())
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(CreateMappings()))
    .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
    .BuildSessionFactory();
}

private static IPersistenceConfigurer ConfigureDatabase()
{
  return MsSqlConfiguration
    .MsSql2008.ShowSql()
    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromAppSetting("MSSqlConnectionString"))
    .ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>();
}

private static AutoPersistenceModel CreateMappings()
{
  return AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Organisation>(new AutomappingConfig())
    .Conventions.Add<CascadeConvention>();
}

private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
{
  new SchemaUpdate(config)
    .Execute(false,true);
}
```

Heres my autoMappingConfig

```
public class AutomappingConfig : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
  public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
  {
    return type.Namespace == "Domain.Model" && type.IsClass;
  }
}
```

And all of my entities inherit this base class:

```
public class BaseEntity<T> where T : BaseEntity<T>
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And an example entity:

```
public class Contact : BaseEntity<Contact>, IAggregateRoot
{
  public virtual String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is it possible that your other classes aren't in the same assembly as 'Organisation'?

Comment: @sJhonny they definitely are in the same assembly.

Comment: What version of FNH and NH are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> BaseEntity is in a different namespace to the entities.

What you may want to do is try putting them in the same namespace.  Also you may want to comment out the check you have above:

```
return type.Namespace == "Domain.Model" && type.IsClass;
```

The above statement may be what is causing you to only map your base classes.  What namespace is your base class in and what namespace are one of your example entities in?

When I run into problems like this I try to simplify things until I find out what is causing my issues.

**Edit:**

After further research I think you need to use the following:

```
.IgnoreBase(typeof(BaseEntity<>));
```

So your code above would be changed to:

```
private static AutoPersistenceModel CreateMappings()
{
  return AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Organisation>(new AutomappingConfig())
    .Conventions.Add<CascadeConvention>()
    .IgnoreBase(typeof(BaseEntity<>));
}
```

This is an excerpt taken from the [FNH Wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping):

> We've added the IgnoreBase
>   call which simply instructs the
>   automapper to ignore the Entity class;
>   you can chain this call as many times
>   as needed.
>
> With this change, we now get our
>   desired mapping. Entity is ignored as
>   far is Fluent NHibernate is concerned,
>   and all the properties (Id in our
>   case) are treated as if they were on
>   the specific subclasses.

Comment: @cole w sorry for the delay in replying, i have tried what you suggested but i still get the same result, a table is created for each class but only with the Id field in.

Comment: @geepie take a look at my edit above and see if this helps you.  I was able to duplicate what you were seeing and this fixed it for me.

Comment: @geepie Also whenever you try to regenerate your schema I would delete the old tables from your db first.  I experienced issues with this unless I deleted them first.

Comment: I agree that `IgnoreBase` is probably what is needed - not `IncludeBase`.  I can't imagine that @geepie would want his DB schema to include the inheritance relationship between BaseEntity and its subclasses.  It's not helpful for every table to join to a single table that dishes out all of the id's.

Comment: @Cole W thanks for your edit, i will take it into account and try again.

Comment: @Cole W Using the ignorebase<> pushed me onto the next error which i was able to fix. Cheers!

Comment: Boo ... no bounty for me.  Glad I was able to help though.

Answer (score 0):

From [Automapping: base-type as an inheritance strategy](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping#Base-type_as_an_inheritance_strategy):

> **Abstract base-classes**
>
> You'll notice that our Entity class is
>   abstract. This is good practice, but
>   for the record, it is not mandatory.
>   If you're experiencing problems, it's
>   unlikely to be this.
>
> In case you're wondering, making the
>   class abstract is like saying "I'll
>   never create this directly, instead I
>   will create derived classes such as
>   Customer and Order (which inherit from
>   Entity)."
>
> The default behavior is to consider
>   abstract classes as layer supertypes
>   and effectively unmapped, you may want
>   to change this for specific scenarios.
>   The easiest way to do this is to use
>   IncludeBase, where T is your
>   entity.

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>(cfg)
  .IncludeBase<BaseEntity>();

AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>(cfg)
  .IncludeBase(typeof(BaseEntity<>));
```

Article: [Auto-mapping generic base classes](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto-mapping_generic_base_classes)

Comment: Thanks for your input. How do i include my base class then as its a BaseEntity of a type, .IncludeBase<BaseEntity<>>(); doesn't work

Comment: I changed my automap to include the base entity but it is still only generating the ID's in the tables. Bit stuck on this, not sure what to try? thanks for your help so far.